# Как получить Id у User.Identity.Name?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Собственно вопрос в заголовке.

Аутентификация в данный момент на куках в "свои" таблицы. Нужно в поле Author записать Id пользователя.

Покажите пожалуйста пример, или же посоветуйте литературу. Спасибо!

Ф-ия

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(CreateViewModel model)
    {           
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (await _context.xWeb_Threads.CountAsync((Thread arg) => arg.Title == model.Title) > 0)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("Title", "A Thread already exist with that title");
                return View(model);
            }

            //var UserName = User.Identity.Name;

            Thread thread = new Thread
            {
                ForumId = model.ForumID,
                Title = model.Title,
                Author = ?,
                Content = model.Content,
                CreationTime = DateTime.UtcNow,
                Posts = new List<Post>(),
            };

            _context.Add(thread);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), new { Title = thread.Title });
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Thread

```
public class Thread
{
    public Thread() => Posts = new List<Post>();

    [Required]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String Title { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public User Author { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Content { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime CreationTime { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int ForumId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Forum Forum { get; set; }
}
```

User

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public int? RoleId { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: например с помощью метода `FindFirstValue`:
`HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);`
или с помощью `FindFirst`: 
`HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value`.
Если Вам нужно получить доступ к контексту вне контроллера, можете заинжектить `IHttpContextAccessor`.

Comment: @ Ares  Спасибо большое за наводку. А записать автору Id лучше как? Было Author = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User), но решили отказаться от дефолтных таблиц AspNetUser и сделали аунтификацию на куках. Соответственно и записывать сейчас иначе нужно.

Comment: Добавить поле AuthorId (int)? Не придется никуда ходить за бесполезным объектом в данном случае.